# Should I migrate from Django 1.2.5 to 1.3.x ?  Are there any undocumented issues?

Tags: python, django, release-management

**Short Question**
Are there any compelling reasons to update Django 1.2.5 to 1.3?  If the noted changes in the release notes do not impact my application directly.

*EDIT:*
To better clarify my question (thanks S.Lott!): Are there any issues *not mentioned* in the Django 1.3's release notes that I should be aware of if upgrading from version 1.2.5?

**Background**
I have done all of my development on 1.2.5 with no troubles.  I will be deploying my application within the next week or two and it's life cycle will be 18 - 24 months of constant use.

**Secondary (more general question)**
Just  prior to a release, is it good practice to get the latest and greatest (stable) version of your dependencies?

Comment: @Adam Lewis: "the noted changes in the release notes do not impact my application directly".  Then don't upgrade.  Why would you even ask?  What's the **real** reason for saying you don't want to upgrade and then asking if you should do something you **already** know you're not going to do?  What information could want?

Comment: @S.Lott: At this point in time I really do not know if I am going to upgrade.  I am trying to get a feel for fast moving projects when it comes to support in the future.  I have been in situations in the past where the only help I could get was upgrade to version 'x' and we can help.

Comment: @Adam Lewis: What information could you want?

Comment: @S.Lott: Thoughts on the best practices regarding upgrading dependencies just before a release.  I am on the fence with one side saying 'if it's not broke, don't fix it', but on the other side I am worried about possible support issues during it's life cycle.

Comment: @Adam Lewis: "Thoughts on the best practices"?  So the bit about Django is irrelevant?  The question seems confusing if it's simply a request for best practices.  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75874/how-quickly-should-i-adopt-new-technology-i-e-new-net-versions-new-vs-version/75927 seems relevant, since the question isn't really about Django.

Comment: @S.Lott: Agreed in the fact that the more generic question on best practices is addressed well in your provided link.  I was also trying to see if there were any other issues with Django 1.3, not mentioned in the release notes.  It appears there is not.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Adam Lewis: "trying to see if there were any other issues with Django 1.3, not mentioned in the release notes"?  Is that your **real** question?  Could you please **update** the question to clarify what you're **really** looking for.  It's rather confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need reasons? Just look at the [release notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/). They do a very good job outlining both new features and backwards incompatible changes. I have been happy to migrate all of my Django projects to 1.3, I'm particularly happier about the changes to the way static files are managed. Class-based views are quite nice, the improved logging support is great. If you have the time go for it. It shouldn't take too much work to migrate. Generally I stay as current as I can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer (again).  I have viewed the release notes, and at the moment none of the changes that I see would directly impact my app.  All I am really using Django for is an ORM with a built in Admin interface to my data.  I will update my question to reflect the release note comment.

Comment: It's ok, don't upgrade then. For what it's worth I've updated a half-dozen projects to 1.3 and I have not had any issues (beyond documented backwards incompatibilities which were easy to deal with).

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to a new version of Django (especially from a directly previous release) is really easy and takes less than ten minutes for one project (if its not super complex).
It it's running for 18 to 24 months I would better upgrade. After one or two more releases of Django (one major release each year) they will simply not support security updates for older versions anymore. To be be save you can make the step to 1.3 and then don't need to upgrade further, except your project is running even longer.

Answer (score 0):

As I once read somewhere, Django has releases mostly because people ask about releases. Other than that, it's perfectly ok to stick to the trunk revision.

Comment: In theory, yes. Django has a strict "clean trunk" policy, so you should be able to run off it even in production without worries of functionality getting broken. However, backwards-incompatible changes are inevitable, and when they occur, you must fix your own code right now, not at your leisure as when developing off a release.